# Why isn't Magento using my custom themes addtocart.phtml instead of the default?

Tags: multistore

I am trying to get my magento site to use the addtocart.phtml from my other theme within my main theme.

currently my themes are setup as follows

```
      app                                  skin
        frontend                             frontend
          mainTheme                            mainTheme
            default                              default
            store1                               store1
            store2                               store2
```

but even if store1 & store2 have their own addtocart.phtml file it uses the one from default, but when I delete the addtocart.phtml from default it still doesn't use the one from store1

I have gone to `configuration --> design` and set it so that the the skin is set to store1 , the template is set to store1 and default is default, but for some reason it just wont play ball, any ideas ?

Comment: Are you missing  design folder app/design/frontend?

Comment: no got the same folders in the skin as I do the app :/

Comment: plus its not even running the correct css and js scripts, I've got 3 separate script files in each of my skin directories, the just say console.log(store1, store2, default) when I goto the home page it loads store1 scripts but when going to the addto cart page it loads the default scripts :/

Comment: The folder structure for the theme should be app/design/frontend not the app/frontend